# Is there a subsequence algorithm in the Standard Library?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for a Standard Library function that returns true if the range `[first2, last2)` is present within the range `[first1, last1)`. Something with a name like `std::is_subsequence`. It seems that something like this would be obvious to be in the Standard but for some reason it's not there (or I just can't find it at the least). Is there a function or method out there that does this?

Comment: It would depend on the container type. What is your list? A vector, list, array, etc?

Comment: Subset or subsequence?

Comment: Do they need to be in order? Do you need them to be contiguous elements? Can it be assumed that your containers are sorted?

Comment: @AndyProwl What's the difference?

Comment: @MemyselfandI: Well, `{1, 2, 3}` is a subsequence (and a subset) of `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`. However, it is also a subset (but not a subsequence) of `{4, 3, 2, 1, 0}` or `{1, 0, 4, 2, 3, 5}`. In other words, the "subset-of" relation does not take ordering into  account, while the "subsequence-of" relation does.

Comment: @AndyProwl Thanks for the clarification. The word that I meant was "subsequence".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::search` in `<algorithm>`

[std::search at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/)
[std:: search at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)

> **Search range for subsequence**
>   Searches the range [first1,last1) for the first occurrence of the sequence defined by [first2,last2), and returns an iterator to its first element, or last1 if no occurrences are found.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some differences here. `Substring` and `subsequence` are different. The former requires continuity and the latter does not.
std::search() can only check substrings, not [subsequences](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144974/using-c-to-check-if-string-s-is-subsequence-of-string-t)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether your sequenses are ordered and how you are going to determine that one sequence is present inside another sequence. For example for ordered sequences there is algorithm `std::include`. For unordered sequences you can check that one sequence is an interval of an other sequence. These are algorithms `std::search` and `std::find_end`.

Comment: Oh and yeah, why `std::search` is paired with `std::find_end` and `std::find` is doing something else? Why not `search_last` instead of `find_last`?

Comment: @ bolov I think that it is named by analogy with member function find_end of std::basic_string